# postfix header_checks

Tags: email, postfix

This is my mail log file on my local RHEL5 system:-

```
From root@achal.com  Mon Jun  4 02:04:23 2012
Return-Path: root@achal.com
X-Original-To: c
Delivered-To: c@achal.com
Received: by www.achal.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
id 9C6C356014; Mon,  4 Jun 2012 02:04:23 -0700 (PDT)

To: c@achal.com
Subject: d
Message-Id: <20120604090423.9C6C356014@www.achal.com>
Date: Mon,  4 Jun 2012 02:04:23 -0700 (PDT)
From: root@achal.com (achal)
```

I want to change Return-Path:  to achal@localdomain.in,
I have tried header_
checks in postfix but i am not able to get the proper format.Can anybody tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check My own hostname, My own domain name & My own network addresses 
[Postfix Basic Configuration | postfix.org](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html)